# Thunderbird ignores my migrated profile and asks to create a new one

Tags: email, thunderbird, windows-11, user-profiles

I am not able to migrate my Thunderbird mail profile to my new laptop on Windows 11 (old computer was Windows 10 though I don't think it matters).  Thunderbird ignores the profile data and asks me to create a new account. Could someone please help me restore my profile from the old computer?

I copied my previous profile folder from my old computer to my new laptop, replacing the "new installation profile" folder that Thunderbird had created on the new laptop when I first installed and used it.

However, when I restarted Thunderbird, expecting it to work as it had on the old computer, instead I got the screen to set up a new account (e.g. asking what my email address is, so that it can query the server to set up accounts).

I put the "new installation profile" folder back, and Thunderbird worked again, displaying my email without asking me to set up anything.  Can someone tell me why the "new installation profile" folder works, and not my previous profile folder from my old computer?

My old computer was running Thunderbird v78.7.0 (64bit), whereas the new laptop is running 102.3.1 (64-bit), though I would expect the newer version to update the profile automatically.  (I know I've been using old versions --Due to GUI scripting reason, I cannot upgrade Thunderbird unless I retune the whole GUI script.)

I even checked the `compatibility.ini` file in both my previous profile folder and the new installation profile folder, and they are identical:

```
[Compatibility]
LastVersion=102.3.1_20220928170044/20220928170044
LastOSABI=WINNT_x86_64-msvc
LastPlatformDir=c:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird
LastAppDir=c:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird
```

(Of course, `compatibility.ini` file from the old profile got updated by the new Thunderbird -- I'm sure it didn't say the last version was 102.3.1 when I was running it on v78.7.0.)

Any help on how to get the old profile up and running would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the directory/file ownerships and permissions?

Answer (score 0):

@DavidPostill: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did check the directory permissions.  I found the problem.  It turns out that the profile directory was corrupted.  When I copied it over again, it worked.  I'll leave this question up in case someone else runs into the same problem.